# needs help with checking an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been asked to integrate

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+\ln(x)}}{x\ln(x)}\,dx$$

and I'm well aware that actually there are some ways to solve this problem, so I challenge myself with a slightly longer solution.
I rewrite above integrand as

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+\left(\sqrt{\ln(x)}\right)^2}}{x\ln(x)}\,dx$$

$\sqrt{\ln(x)} = \tan(a)$

$\dfrac{1}{2x\sqrt{\ln(x)}}\, dx = \sec^2(a)\, da$.

and so, above expression turn into:

$$2\int\frac{\sec^2(a)\sqrt{1+\tan^2(a)}}{\tan(a)}\, da$$

$$2\int\frac{\sec^3(a)}{\tan(a)}\, da$$

$$2\int\sec^2(a)\csc(a)\, da$$

Here I using integral by parts

$$\int f'g = fg-\int fg'$$

I took,

$$\sec^2(a)= g' ，\tan(a) = g ，\csc(a) = f，-\csc(a)\cot(a)=f'$$

and so above integral resulting:

$$ 2\left[\csc(a)\tan(a)+ \ln\vert \sin(a)+\tan(a)\vert\right]+C$$

and here the consequences of those variable

opposite       : $\sqrt{\ln(x)}$

adjacent       : $1$

hypotenuse  : $\sqrt{\ln(x)+1}$

$$ 2\left[\sqrt{\ln(x)+1}+\ln\left\vert \frac{\sqrt{\ln(x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(x)+1}}
+\sqrt{\ln(x)}\right\vert\right]+C$$

Personally, I don't think I made mistakes but when I check on the calculator, calculator ruled that this answer is wrong, I've been tracking i back over and over but i can't find where I did go wrong, 
so please help me to identify my mistakes since if this right the difference should be no more than a constant.

Comment: Formatting note:  You are persistently omitting brackets, as in the first expression, which ought to read  "\int\frac{\sqrt{1+\ln(x)}}{x\ln(x)}dx" and then similarly throughout.

Comment: @lulu thanks, i'll try edit that

Comment: It's possible that you just have an equivalent form of the answer.

Comment: Note, by the way, the use of the backslash \ in front of functions like ln.  Absent that syntax, the system treats it as text which, I think, doesn't look nearly as good.

Comment: @GerryMyerson no,i checked this on integral calculator  already

Comment: Did you try differentiating your answer to see whether you get back to the original integrand? By the way, your formatting still isn't working.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, i still green with latex ,i may need some time

Comment: There, I fixed the MathJax. I think one of the lines was just repeated, so I deleted it. (It was literally the same integrand.)

Comment: @KM101 your help is much appreciate

Comment: Its quite simple, let $ln(x) = y$, then $1/x*dx = dy$, and use substitution to solve it. You should be able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all of your work is correct, apart from the integration by parts step. For $\displaystyle\int \sec^2(a)\csc(a) \, \mathrm da$, let $u = \csc(a)$ and $\mathrm dv = \sec^2(a) \, \mathrm da$ (as you did). Hence, $\mathrm du = -\csc(a)\cot(a) \, \mathrm da$ and $v = \tan(a)$. Using $\displaystyle \int u \, \mathrm dv = uv-\displaystyle\int v \, \mathrm du$, you get:

$$\int \sec^2(a)\csc(a) \, \mathrm da = \csc(a)\cot(a)-\int -\tan(a)\csc(a)\cot(a) \, \mathrm da$$

Clearly, $\tan(a)\cot(a) = 1$ and you can get rid of the double negatives, so:

$$\int \sec^2(a)\csc(a) \, \mathrm da = \csc(a)\cot(a)+\int \csc(a) \, \mathrm da$$

It seems like your only problem was integrating $\csc(a)$, which gives $-\ln\vert \csc(a)+\cot(a)\vert+C$ and not $+\ln\vert \sin(a)+\tan(a)\vert+C$. The rest of your answer, however, is correct, so what you'll get is:

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+\ln(x)}}{x\ln(x)}\, \mathrm dx = 2\left[\sqrt{\ln(x)+1}-\ln\left\vert \frac{\sqrt{\ln(x)+1}}{\sqrt{\ln(x)}}
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(x)}}\right\vert\right]+C$$

**Extra:** I'm suspecting that was just an accident. But here's an explanation in case it wasn't. In order to see how that works, recall that $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da} [\csc(a)] = -\csc(a)\cot(a)$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}[\cot(a)] = -\csc^2(a)$, so adding them together gives $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da} [\csc(a)+\cot(a)] = -\csc(a)[\csc(a)+\cot(a)]$ (just factoring). Isolating for $\csc(a)$ gives:

$$\csc(a) = -\dfrac{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}[\csc(a)+\cot(a)]}{\csc(a)+\cot(a)}$$

The RHS is just $-\dfrac{f'(a)}{f(a)}$, which just gives $-\ln\vert f(a)\vert+C$ when integrated by substitution, so:

$$\displaystyle\int \csc(a) \, \mathrm da = -\ln \vert \csc(a)+\cot(a)\vert +C$$

Comment: thank you so much to did such length , but isn't $ -(\ln |csc(x)+cot(x)|)$. is equal with  $\ln tan(x)+sin(x)$ i mean $- ln x = ln \frac{1}{x}$ right?

Comment: Glad to have helped! They’re being added, not multiplied, so no.

Comment: there is the revised comment , please check them out.

Comment: I understood what you meant. Remember$\dfrac{1}{a+b} \color{red}{\neq \dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}}$.

Comment: In case my previous comment wasn't clear enough, $\dfrac{1}{\csc(a)+\cot(a)}\color{red}{\neq \dfrac{1}{\csc(a)}+\dfrac{1}{\cot(a)}}$, which is what you were implying.

Comment: no,that's really clear actually ! once again ,thank you really...i don't know how long i keep doing such shameful fundamental mistake in the future if it's not corrected today :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct up to the point

$$2\int\frac{\sec^3(a)}{\tan(a)} da $$

The integration-by-parts afterwards is incorrect. In fact, there is no need to perform integration-by-parts. Instead,

$$2\int\frac{\sec^3(a)}{\tan(a)} da = 2\int\frac{\sec^2(a)}{\tan^2(a)} d(\sec(a))
= 2\int\frac{\sec^2(a)}{\sec^2(a)-1} d(\sec(a))$$
$$= \int\left(2 + \frac{1}{\sec(a)-1} - \frac{1}{\sec(a)+1} \right)d(\sec(a))$$
$$= 2\sec(a)  + \ln(\sec(a)-1) - \ln(\sec(a)+1) +C $$
$$= 2\sqrt{\ln(x)+1}  + \ln\frac{\sqrt{\ln(x)+1} -1}{\sqrt{\ln(x)+1} +1}  +C $$

Note that the substitution $\sqrt{\ln(x)}=\tan (a) $ is only valid for the domain $x>1$.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the answer, I solved it for you. Let me know if you have questions.

[image]